# While loop isn't returning its condition

Tags: python

```
attempts=0

number=int(input("Enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))

while number<0 and number>100:
    attempts=attempts+1
    number=int(input("Number is invalid. Please enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))

attempts=attempts+1    
print("Number of attempts for inputting a valid number: ", attempts)
```

I'm writing a program where an inputted number is validated from the range 0 to 100. If it's invalid, the number will be rejected and a prompt will be shown to re-input a number. I then need to output the number of attempts it took to input a valid number.

So far, when an integer greater than 0 and less than 100 is inputted, the program works fine. If an integer, let's say -50 is inputted, the prompt should be shown and it then needs to re-input the number - but my while loop isn't returning its condition and it goes to show an output of:

```
Enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: -50 
Number of attempts for inputting a valid number:  1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A number cannot be both <0 and > 100.  I think you mean ```or``` and not ```and```

Comment: @user56700 `not in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is here while `number<0 and number>100:` **or** means at least one condition is correct but **and** means all the conditions are correct.
Now look at the condition No number can fulfill your condition like `less than 0 and greater than 100 at a sametime.` so you can use or operation so one of the conditions are meet the requirements then code execute.

```
attempts=0
invalid_attempts=0
number=int(input("Enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))
while number<0 or number>100:
    
    number=int(input("Number is invalid. Please enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))
    invalid_attempts+=1
attempts=attempts+1    
print("Number of attempts for inputting a valid number: ", attempts)
print("Number of attempts for inputting a Invalid number: ", invalid_attempts)
```

Comment: `attempts` will always be 1???

Comment: Why is it necessary?

Comment: yup attempts are always 1 when the attempt is valid but it can provide info on valid and invalid attempts. if you want you can further upgrade this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think in `while` loop, the condition should be `or` not `and`.

```
attempts=0

number=int(input("Enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))

while number<0 or number>100:
    attempts=attempts+1
    number=int(input("Number is invalid. Please enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))

attempts=attempts+1    
print("Number of attempts for inputting a valid number: ", attempts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "or" instand of "and":

```
attempts=0

number=int(input("Enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))

while number<0 or number>100:
    attempts=attempts+1
    number=int(input("Number is invalid. Please enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))

attempts=attempts+1
print("Number of attempts for inputting a valid number: ", attempts)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion:

```
attempts=0

number=int(input("Enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))

while number not in range(0, 101):
    attempts=attempts+1
    number=int(input("Number is invalid. Please enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: "))

attempts=attempts+1    
print("Number of attempts for inputting a valid number: ", attempts)
```

Result:

```
Enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: -1
Number is invalid. Please enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: 101
Number is invalid. Please enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: 100
Number of attempts for inputting a valid number:  3
Enter a number from a range of 0 to a 100: 0
Number of attempts for inputting a valid number:  1
```